# Possible to log data from a game chat?

Tags: java

I looked about but were unable to find if anything of such exist.

Is it possible to construct a java program, which can read sudden strings from a chat inside a game?

It would be used to log sudden data to a mysql to comparison.

If any knows something of this sort, any direction is high appreciated.

Comment: "Sudden strings" that's a new one :) You may need to provide more context for anyone to be able to answer this question properly. What game is it? Do you need it immediately or can wait?

Comment: It's for Diablo 3. When someone in guild loots an item I wish to save that name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. You would need to have access to the game's methods in order to know when a new chat entry appears, and how to get its content.

Appart from that, as [Kenyanke explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26342893/3283203), some games might save a chatlog on your computer, yet it won't help you anyway, since you have no idea of when these logs get saved, or if they do get saved for that matter.

Comment: Was hoping it wouldn't get so complicated. But thanks